# Generate a Markov chain in Python using an object's attribute as state

Tags: python, markov

Suppose I have several different states in the form of an Enum:

```
class State(Enum):
    State1 = 1
    State2 = 2
    State3 = 3
```

I define transition probabilities between the states:

```
transition_probabilities = [
    [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
    [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
]
```

I know have a selection of different objects in the form of dataclasses that have as an attribute a particular state:

```
@dataclass
class Thing:
    name: str
    state: State

things = [
    Thing('a', State.State1),
    Thing('b', State.State1),
    Thing('c', State.State2),
    Thing('d', State.State2),
    Thing('e', State.State2),
    Thing('f', State.State3),
]
```

What I'd like to do is generate a sequence of objects using something like `random.choices` where the probability of sampling the next object depends on the state of the current object, eg if my first object is `Thing('a', State.State1)`, then I have an 80% chance of sampling from `[Thing('a', State.State1), Thing('b', State.State1)]`, a 10% chance of sampling from the State2 things and a 10% chance of sampling from the State3 things, and similarly with the other transition probabilities.

Edit: To clarify, if I start with an object in state 1 then I want to transition to a new state with the defined probabilities and then uniformly sample a single object from the objects that have the state that I transitioned to. I want to repeat this until I've generated a sequence of a set length (eg 20)

I can't think of a good way to do this using this current set up - is it possible and if not how should I set it up so that it is?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the relationship between Thing and state? I mean you have a 3x3 transition matrix meaning that there are three possible states, but you defined also 6 thing objects: from 'a' to 'f'. Are just they labels of the three states?

Comment: There is no real relationship - I my real application I have 20 different objects (which have more attributes than shown here} and each one is in one of the 3 states. The State enum just represents the possible states each object can have. Once the object has been defined with a state, it doesn't change

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you want to generate random paths: from a random object, you want to sample next states according to the transition prob. until a terminal state or max steps are reached, right? Suppose the path starts from 'a' which is in state 1, I have 80% change to stay in state 1 so how I decide between 'a' and 'b'? I mean the path can be 'a' -> 'a' with 80% change but also 'a' -> 'b', or 'a' -> {'a', 'b'} (because they share the same state). I think you should add a rule that specifies how objects interacts, or say that objects with the same state should be grouped.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of it - if I'm in state 1 then I want to transition to a new state with the defined probabilities and then uniformly sample a single object from the objects that have the state that I transitioned to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution that generates a random path (you can think of it as a sort of random walk):

```py
import numpy as np

from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass

# NOTE: values adjusted to use States as indices
class State(Enum):
    State1 = 0
    State2 = 1
    State3 = 2

@dataclass
class Thing:
    name: str
    state: State

transition_probabilities = [
    [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
    [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
]

things = [
    Thing('a', State.State1),
    Thing('b', State.State1),
    Thing('c', State.State2),
    Thing('d', State.State2),
    Thing('e', State.State2),
    Thing('f', State.State3),
]

# group objects by same state
groups = dict()  # dict: state -> Thing

for obj in things:
    if obj.state not in groups:
        groups[obj.state] = []

    groups[obj.state].append(obj)

indices = np.arange(len(things))
all_states = list(groups.keys())

# generate a random path
def generate_path(max_length=20):
    # start from a random object (and so state); add it to the path
    current_obj = things[np.random.choice(indices)]
    path = [current_obj]

    # you can add a stopping criterion (e.g. terminal states)
    for _ in range(max_length):
        state = current_obj.state
        probs = transition_probabilities[state.value]

        # sample next state according to transition probabilities
        new_state, = np.random.choice(all_states, size=1, p=probs)

        # randomly sample an object in that state
        new_object, = np.random.choice(groups[new_state], size=1)
        current_obj = new_object

        # update the path
        path.append(current_obj)

    return path
```

An example usage:

```py
random_path = generate_path()

for obj in random_path:
    print(obj.name, obj.state)
```

That may print:

```
f State.State3
c State.State2
...
e State.State2
c State.State2
```

The function `generate_path()` outputs a path with `max_length + 1` objects. You can adapt this code according to your own application. Hope it helps.